# Big Query insertAll method in Java is not reflecting the changes in Table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, java

I am trying to insert data into a Big Query table using the method `insertAll`.

This is how my insert method code looks like -

```
public void insertIntoTable(String datasetName, String tableName) {
    TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);
    String fieldName = "testField";

    Map<String, Object> rowContent = new HashMap<>();
    rowContent.put(fieldName, "testVal");


    InsertAllResponse response = bigquery.insertAll(InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId).addRow("rowId", rowContent).build());

    if (response.hasErrors()) {
      for (Map.Entry<Long, List<BigQueryError>> entry : response.getInsertErrors().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString());
      }
    }
}
```

Although it is not throwing any error, but still data is not getting inserted into my table.

As per there access-control document: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control

To use the `insertAll` method the user would require `bigquery.tables.updateData` permission. And for using that permission the user need to have the `bigquery.dataEditor` role, which I already have.

There is no issue with the permission because in another method I am creating a table, and the table is getting created successfully in Big Query.

The tableName and datasetName is also correct, I tested it in the debug mode.

Another issue that I can think of is type mismatch issue. But thats not the case either, because I checked it and the type is String only. Attached schema details below -

[image]

Can there be any other issue which I may be missing out here?

============================================= 
Edited Part - 
It has been pointed out to me that the stream data does not reflect in the UI, for viewing the data we have to query the table.

Now I am facing a new issue. 
I executed the above function 6 times, each time with a different value. Basically I was changing only this line - 
`rowContent.put(fieldName, "testVal");` 
The first time when I executed the method, the insert value was `testVal`.

The other five times when I executed the method, I modified this line of code - 
Execution 1: `rowContent.put(fieldName, "testVal1");` 
Execution 2: `rowContent.put(fieldName, "testVal2");` 
Execution 3: `rowContent.put(fieldName, "testVal3");` 
Execution 4: `rowContent.put(fieldName, "testVal4");` 
Execution 5: `rowContent.put(fieldName, "testVal5");`

So ideally in my table there should be 6 rows with the values - 
testVal 
testVal1 
testVal2 
testVal3 
testVal4 
testVal5

But I am able to see only two rows when I am querying my table.

[image]

Why it is showing only 2 rows instead of 6?

Comment: "data is not getting inserted into my table". Did you try querying it? The UI does not show rows in the streaming buffer unless you query them explicitly.

Comment: Wow. . .I didn't knew that, while querying I am able to see the data, but now I am facing a different issue. I ran the same function 5 times now with different values "testVal1", "testVal2". "testVal3". "testVal4", "testVal5". Now when I am querying it, it is showing only 2 rows. One with the value "testVal" and another with the value "testVal5". Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard do know why I am facing the issue mentioned in the comment?

Comment: I don't understand what you are describing. Updating your question is a better idea than adding a comment.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I updated the question with the new issue which I am facing.

Comment: When streaming into partitioned tables, newly arriving data will be temporarily associated with the NULL partition while in the streaming buffer, therefore excluded by some queries. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaming_into_partitioned_tables. Did the 4 missing rows eventually appear in your query?

Comment: @Jinjun No they didn't appeared yet.

Comment: There is an ongoing issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/3344, looks like you are affected. You can watch over that thread and wait for the fix.